# Git Remote Repository Check-Out Problem

Tags: git, fetch

I've just started using Git and have never used a versioning system before. I am trying to setup a git repository on my web server and one on my local computer.

I am doing the following on the server (I run the commands in a project folder ~/project):

```
git init
git add .
git commit -am "Initial Commit"
```

Then on my laptop i'm using:

```
git init
git remote add remote_server ssh://[name]@[server].com/~/project
git fetch remote_server
```

When i've done that the following is displayed

```
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
```

However, once this is completed there is nothing in the local folder and if I check the log I get:

> fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to call log on an unborn branch so there's not going to be anything there. Clone first, or if you have a git repo ready, pull it.

Answer (score 3):

`git fetch` will fetch the remote branches but not merge them into your local branch(es). You can either:

- use `git clone` in the first place, that will place all the changes on your local default branch automatically.
- use `git merge remote_server master` to now manually merge the changes into your currently checked out branch (master).
- use `git pull` which performs a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`.

Comment: `git pull origin master` worked for me.  Would love to know why this happens though...